# ARM Templates - Convert array of objects to array of object's field

Tags: azure, templates, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template which deploys 2 linked templates:

1. linked template #1 -- creates a 10 storage accounts and returns an array of objects - each object consists of a property called "storageName".
2. linked template #2 -- gets as input an array of storage names and key vault name. It fetches the storage key and uploads it to key vault as a secret (for each storage name in the array).

**The problem** - is that the output of #1 is not in the same shape of #2's input.

## Linked Template #1 output:

```
[
      {
        "name": "storage1"
      },
      {
        "name": "storage2"
      },
      {
        "name": "storage3"
      }
]
```

## Linked Template #2 input:

```
[
      "storage1",
      "storage2",
      "storage3"
]
```

### How can the parent template do the conversion from #1 to #2 ?

Comment: I can adjust the input/output of the linked templates of course - but I don't want to.

Comment: According to [Get values from linked template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#get-values-from-linked-template). We could get the vaule from the linked template. If we want to deploy the multiple resource we could use the arm [copy function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple).

Comment: can you provide a working example? I will accept this kind of answer